# Connect to socket

Tags: php, sockets

i would like to connect in an existed socket (i have IP and port) which is sent me data and i want to get it.

Do you know how can i do that?

Until now, i have written below:

```
$addr = 'XXXXXXXX';
$port = XXXXX;

$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
socket_connect($socket, $addr, $port);
socket_getsockname($socket, $addr, $port);
$counter = 1;
while ($counter < 5)
{
    $input = socket_read($socket, 1024);
    if ($input !== '')
    {
        $counter++;
        echo $input."<br><br>";
    }
}
socket_close($socket);
```

The problem is that i do not get data from the socket. The socket in which i connected has no problem for sure. I send test data and the response is squares or symbols. My page is UTF8

Comment: Looks good. What's the problem?

Comment: The problem is that i do not get data from the socket. The socket i connected has no problem for sure. I send test data and the response is squares or symbols. My page is UTF8

Comment: Can you paste the response you're getting?

Comment: It is something like that �. Should i run this php from command line?

Comment: some idea? some familiar code for what i want to do?